# Storing dates in a list using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two textboxes and a button, both textbox have calender attach to them. I want to store the dates which are between the first textbox and second textbox in a list, I am invoking following method on button click.

```
private void CollectDates()
    {
        DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text);
        DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTillDate.Text);
        List<DateTime> datelist = new List<DateTime>();
        for (StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text); StartDate < Convert.ToDateTime(txtTillDate.Text); StartDate.AddDays(1))
        {
            datelist.Add(StartDate);
        }
    }
```

But I am getting error after storing the first date in the list: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. 
I think my loop is running endlessly, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are the initial dates? BTW, is there a meaning to all this or it is just an exercise?

Comment: from the textboxes "txtFromDate" and "txtTillDate". I need date collection to perform certain task

Comment: What are the values in these 2 text boxes?

Comment: The `StartDate.AddDays(1)` command does nothing. Change it to `StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(1)` (not tested)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime.AddDays()` does not change the datetime you must assign its return value. Like

```
StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(1)
```

Comment: Indeed, it's like saying: int i = 0; i + 1; (although this wouldn't compile). You are not adding 1 to i. You are effectively creating a new int and doing nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed an infinite loop. You're stating that if the start date is less than the end date, add start date to the list. It'll keep doing this for infinity as start date should always (in theory) be less than the end date. The add days function isn't assigned to a variable so it never gets added to the start date.

Also another piece of advice with .Net datetime is to use the in-built compare function.

[DateTime Compare function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Why would you prefer to use `Compare` over the much more readable less-than/greater-than operators?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void CollectDates()
{
    DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text);
    DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTillDate.Text);
    List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();

    DateTime currentDate = StartDate;

    while(currentDate <= EndDate)
    {
        dateList.Add(currentDate);
        currentDate.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try linq:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, (int)endDate.Subtract(startDate).TotalDays)
          .Select(d => startDate.AddDays(d))
          .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
for (int i =0; i<(EndDate-StartDate).Days; i++)
        {
            datelist.Add(StartDate.AddDays(i));
        }
```